# Getting to a Number by adding the elements of an array

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, recursion

So I've been trying to wrap my head around recursion and came across this problem and got stuck.
Here it goes...

I've been given an array of elements and a positive integer and I have to find the number of ways get to the positive integer by adding the elements of array(using each elements only once).

For example:

```
array = [1, 4, 9]
n = 10
```

So the answer will be 1 i.e. (1,9)

Please try to be elaborate as I'm already having a difficult time understanding recursion

This is what I came up with while working with the problem I also tried doing it with loops but it wasn't any success either.

```
def _Sum(X, li):
    if X == 0:
        return 1
    if X < 0:
        return 0
    if X > 0:
        ways = 0
        for i in range(len(li)):
            ways += _Sum(X-li[i], li)
        return ways
```

Comment: This problem is a little advanced for someone just starting to learn recursion. I would recommend looking at some other problems like Fibonacci or searching a BST before tackling this one

Comment: @MitchelPaulin I've successfully programmed the aforementioned problems and was progressing smoothly until I got stuck at this one

Answer (score 1):

Since you do not show any code, I'll just give you a hint. Show more of your work if you want more details. I'll ignore the ambiguous cases of `[0]` (does that have one way or two ways?) and `n == 0` (does the empty sum count?).

if `array` is empty, the answer is `1` if `n` is zero and is `0` otherwise.

If `array` has more than one element, the number of ways to sum a sub-array of `array` to get the value `n` is equal to the number of ways to sum a sub-array of `array[1:]` to get the value `n` (meaning we do not use the value of `array[0]` in the overall sum) plus the number of ways to sum a sub-array of `array[1:]` to get the value of `n - array[0]` (meaning we do use the value of `array[0]` in the overall sum).

---

Now that you have shown your own code, here is a routine that solves your problem. This does return `_Sum(0, [1])` as `0`, since it counts the empty sum as the way to sum to zero. If you do not like that, write an outer routine that prohibits `X` from being zero then call my routine.

There are routines that avoid recursion and would be more efficient. This routine could also be modified to avoid using a slice of the input list, to be more efficient, but the routine as written is simple.

```
def _Sum(X, li):
    """Return the number of sub-lists of list `li` that sum to `X`.
    This assumes list `li` has only positive integers.
    """
    if len(li) == 0:
        if X == 0:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
    else:
        return _Sum(X, li[1:]) + _Sum(X - li[0], li[1:])
```

For an elaboration, note that my routine has a "base case" that checks for the simplest possibility. Here, that means checking the empty list. If a particular call is not a base case, my code reduces the problem to one or more smaller problems. Here, that means removing the first element of the list. In your problem, there are two ways to get the overall sum to get the target value: include the first list value or leave it out. Hence we call the routine recursively twice and add the two results. Is that clear?

---

Last, you asked what is wrong with your code. Simply, your algorithm is wrong. It is not clear to me why you thought that algorithm would work. Basically, you keep subtracting one of your elements from the target value until it is no longer positive, and if it reached zero exactly you add one to the number of ways. But if you look at the example

```
print(_Sum(2, [1, 2])
```

your code subtracts the first value `1` from `2` repeatedly until it reaches zero then subtracts the second value `2` from `2` until it quickly reaches zero. That counted as two ways.

A working algorithm like mine needs to change both the target value and the list, not just the target value. Yours did not do that so it fails.

Comment: I've edited my question to show the code I came up with, would really appreciate if you could tell me what went wrong there

Comment: @AnirudhSharma: I can't really say since you do now show the code of the `_powerSum` routine. Does that first `if` statement mean that the members of the list are guaranteed to be positive and that one of the counted "ways" could be the empty sum which sums to zero? And since the routine you now show does not use recursion, would you accept a non-recursive solution to your problem?

Comment: I'm so sorry about not being clear... yes, the elements of the list are guaranteed to be positive and no, ways cannot be an empty sum and also '_powerSum' was a typo the function that I meant to call was '_Sum ' recursively. Since I'm trying to understand recursion a recursive solution is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Solution may vary depending on expected time complexity. If you just want to make it work (brute force), I'll give you a tip. For each element, you can either choose it to your sum or ignore it. So you have exactly 2^n possibilities. Now you just have to somehow generate all of them. You can do it using recursion. It is quite hard though to avoid counting same stuff. So let's try to make our recursive function choose the first element that we'll use. Then, run it again, but make it choose an element that is strictly after the first one, and so on. It should look like that:

```
Fun(prev, sum, value, array)
        if(sum == value)
             ++result
        for i from prev + 1 to size(array)
              Fun(i, sum + array[i], value, array)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd create every combination of the array items and check them.

```
import itertools

def combinations(lst_items):
    Combinations = []
    for item in map(list, itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=len(lst_items))):
        cCombo = [lst_items[index] for index,i in enumerate(item) if i == 1]
        Combinations.append(cCombo)
    return Combinations

def combo_matches(array, target):
    return [i for i in combinations(array) if sum(i) == target]

combo_matches([1,4,9],10)
[[1, 9]]

combo_matches([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],15)
[[7, 8],
 [6, 9],
 [5, 10],
 [4, 5, 6],
 [3, 5, 7],
 [3, 4, 8],
 [2, 6, 7],
 [2, 5, 8],
 [2, 4, 9],
 [2, 3, 10],
 [2, 3, 4, 6],
 [1, 6, 8],
 [1, 5, 9],
 [1, 4, 10],
 [1, 3, 5, 6],
 [1, 3, 4, 7],
 [1, 2, 5, 7],
 [1, 2, 4, 8],
 [1, 2, 3, 9],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

Comment: @Anirudh Sharma -- does this not answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

Previous answers are correct, here is another way of doing the same thing except it does NOT use brute force and only does it for two number check

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python

def sumsToTarget(arr, k):
    arr.sort()
    lhs = 0
    rhs = len(arr)-1
    while lhs < rhs:
        sum = arr[lhs] + arr[rhs]
        if sum == k:
            print'sum of',arr[lhs],'and',arr[rhs],'is',sum
            lhs += 1
        elif sum < k:
            lhs += 1
        else:
            rhs -= 1

arr = [8,6,5,2,4,1,9]
k = 10
sumsToTarget (arr,k)
```

[image]

Comment: Checking only for two numbers will not suffice as I need to find all possible subsets